# FSInit() - "CE_BAD_PARTITION"

Tags: pic, spi, fat32

I am using a PIC18F26K80 and an XC8 compiler. I am trying to initialise an SD card and create a file. I have simply formatted the SD card on Windows to have a "FAT32" file system and an "Allocation unit size" of 512 bytes. The capacity of the SD card is 2GB. I am using the MDD library from the MLA Legacy version. My main is the following:

```
FSFILE * file;
char sendBuffer[22] = "This is test string 1";

//**************************************************
// main function
//**************************************************

int main()
{
    initIO();
    LATBbits.LATB0 = 0;

    // Initialise SPI and SD-card
    while ( !MDD_MediaDetect() );

    // Initialize the device
    while ( !FSInit() );

    // Initialize 
#ifdef ALLOW_WRITES

    // Create a new file
    file = FSfopenpgm ( "FILE.TXT", "w" );
    if ( file == NULL )
        while(1);

    // Write 21 1-byte objects from sendBuffer into the file
    if ( FSfwrite ( (void *) sendBuffer, 1, 21, file ) != 21 )
        while(1);

    // Close the file
    if ( FSfclose ( file ) )
    while(1);

#endif

    LATBbits.LATB0 = 1;         //LED

    while(1) {}

    return (0);
}
```

The program gets stuck inside the function "FSInit()" and the error I get from the function is "CE_BAD_PARTITION", which means "The boot record is bad".

The "initIO()" function is the following:

```
//==============================================================================
// void initIO( void );
//==============================================================================
// Sets the pins on the PIC to input or output and determines the speed of the
// internal oscilaltor
// input: none
// return: none
//==============================================================================
void initIO()
{
    OSCCON = 0x75;                  // Clock speed = 32MHz (4x8Mhz)

    TRISA = 0;
    TRISB = 0;
    TRISC = 0;

    TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0;           //LED

    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 0;           // set SCL pin as output
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1;           // set RC4 pin as input
    TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 0;
    TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 0;
}
```

Comment: try formatting SD card with SDCard formatter. select option as "Erase Full" then it will erase all sections of SD card which normal format option cant do. Download it from this link : https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Comment: @Amol I tried it. It did erase everything, but I am still getting the same error.